# Why is this PHP array not the same?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not understanding why the array:

```
<? $data = array( 'items[0][type]' => 'screenprint'); ?>
```

Is not the same as

```
<? echo $data['items'][0]['type']; ?>
```

I'm trying to add to the array but can't seem to figure out how?

Comment: is the first one your original array or is it just what you think it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array( 'items[0][type]' => 'screenprint')
```

This is an array which has one key which is named "items[0][type]" which has one value. That's not the same as an array which has a key `items` which has a key `0` which has a key `type`. PHP doesn't care that the key kinda looks like PHP syntax, it's just one string. What you want is:

```
$data = array('items' => array(0 => array('type' => 'screenprint')));
```

I hope it's obvious that that's a very different data structure.

Comment: The API I am working with is saying that doesn't work. It says the top example I gave is how it's suppose to be formatted. But I need to push to that array with more keys like: items[1][type] => screenprint

Comment: I don't know your API and it hardly makes sense.

Comment: How do I get an array change from this: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [items[0][type]] => screenprint
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [items[1][type]] => screenprint
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [items[2][type]] => screenprint
        )

)

to this:

Array
(
    [items[0][type]] => screenprint
    [items[1][type]] => screenprint
    [items[2][type]] => screenprint
)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$data = [
    'items' => [['type' => 'screenprint']]
];
echo $data['items'][0]['type'];
```